# How do I get Gmail to start on my second desktop window?

Tags: gnome, compiz, gmail

I've got the Compiz Place Windows plugin working for most of my apps, but I can't get Gmail to open on a specified desktop window/viewport.

Under CompizConfig Settings Manager >> Place Windows >> Fixed Window Placement >> Windows with fixed viewport, I have `class=Pidgin, x=2, y=1`, and that works fine, but I can't get Gmail to place properly.

I've tried class=Prism, title=Gmail, title=gmail ...

The Gmail Prism config is from the `prism-google-mail 1.0b3+svn20100210r62050-0ubuntu2` package.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Click new in the "Windows with fixed viewport" section, then click the plus button, then select "Window Title", then click "Grab", then click over the Gmail Window. It will grab the correct window title.

Comment: Yeah, tried that, it gives the `class=Prism` and once it's loaded, the title is something like "Gmail - Inbox (1) - me@gmail.com". While it's loading the title starts at "gmail" then changes to "Gmail".

Comment: @Tom I tried a couple of methods to override the name, but was unsuccessful. There are many Firefox extensions that can do that. I managed to install "Customize Titlebar" after modifying it a little bit, but it didn't work. Also tried to load Gmail in a iframe and created a Prism applet, but Gmail kills the iframe.

Comment: Thanks @lovinglinux, hopefully someone who's figured it out will stumble onto this question one day. Until then I'll just have to keep moving it manually.